# Edit Model from Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model

I have the next tables on my DB:

```
Users:
   id
   userName
   pass

    1
    |
    *

Users_Groups:
   id_user
   id_group
   delegate(bool)

    *
    |
    1

Groups:
   id
   GroupName
   ...
```

Im using entity framework to create a model, using add-> EF data model... selectin the 3 tables...
geting a .edmx file

but i get the models:

```
-Users
-users_Groups
-Groups
```

and I just want

```
-Users
-Groups (whit the delegate value)
```

how can i edit the model or how can i create a new model to do it?

Comment: Try this link: http://www.em64t.net/2011/03/organizing-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-part-3-of-3/

Comment: The designer will not remove the join table because of the delegate column you have in your tables. Note that what you have in the database is that the delegate column describes the relation ship (because it is on the join table) but you want to change it to describe the Groups in your model which is not equivalent semantically. I am not sure if what you try to do is even possible to achieve - e.g. what should happen if you have just Groups entity with delegate property set? How the property is supposed to be saved to the database if you are missing the id_user value?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Delegate property logically describe the Group or the User? Or the combination User-Group?

Your model says that it's a property of the User-Group combination and as such the User-Group combination becomes an entity of its own, because it has properties other than two foreign keys.

If your Group logically has one (and only one) User as it's delegate then you should add the UserId as a foreign key property of the Group. If many users can be delegates for many groups then it should be either as it is now (a separate UserGroup entity with the Delegate property) or you can have 2 join tables, one that describes normal users of a group and the other that describes the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

i found my solution on here: 
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=245ed00edb4c374e&id=245ED00EDB4C374E!132

on page 76, on 2.2.5 "Mapping Many to Many table as 2 Many to Many Associations"

tks to all